# How to define documentation on custom command (using Get-Command or Get-Help)

Tags: powershell, documentation-generation, powershell-5.0, powershell-v5.1

Let's say I have a custom command:

```
function Search-ForStringInFile($string)
{
        ls -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "$string" -List | Select Path
}
```

And I want to be able to run `Get-Help Search-ForStringInFile` or `Get-Command Search-ForStringInFile` to get a description of what the command does.

> Description: Searches for keyword in all files in / under current
>   directory

Is there special comment syntax I can use on the `function` to add this documentation?

Comment: [Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-3.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called Comment based help.  The PowerShell ISE has a really great snippet for doing exactly what you want to do, in fact.  Simply hit Control+J and choose 'Cmdlet - Advanced Function' to load a snippet I'll provide below:

```
<#
.Synopsis
   Short description
.DESCRIPTION
   Long description
.EXAMPLE
   Example of how to use this cmdlet
.EXAMPLE
   Another example of how to use this cmdlet
#>
function Verb-Noun
{
}
```

Once you fill in values for each of these above ([see the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-6#comment-based-help-keywords) for all of the available fields) and hit F5, help will appear within your function.

```
PS>Get-Help Verb-Noun
NAME
    Verb-Noun

SYNOPSIS
    Short description


SYNTAX
    Verb-Noun [-Param1] <Object> [-Param2 <Int32>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]

    Verb-Noun [-Param3 <String>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    Long description


PARAMETERS
    -Param1 <Object>
        Param1 help description

        Required?                    true
        Position?                    1
        Default value                
        Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue, ByPropertyName)
        Accept wildcard characters?  false

    -Param2 <Int32>
        Param2 help description

        Required?                    false
        Position?                    named
        Default value                0
        Accept pipeline input?       false
        Accept wildcard characters?  false

    -Param3 <String>
        Param3 help description

        Required?                    false
        Position?                    named
        Default value                
        Accept pipeline input?       false
        Accept wildcard characters?  false

    -WhatIf [<SwitchParameter>]

        Required?                    false
        Position?                    named
        Default value                
        Accept pipeline input?       false
        Accept wildcard characters?  false

    -Confirm [<SwitchParameter>]

        Required?                    false
        Position?                    named
        Default value                
        Accept pipeline input?       false
        Accept wildcard characters?  false

    <CommonParameters>
        This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
        ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
        OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable. For more information, see 
        about_CommonParameters (https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216). 

INPUTS
    Inputs to this cmdlet (if any)


OUTPUTS
    Output from this cmdlet (if any)


NOTES


        General notes

    -------------------------- EXAMPLE 1 --------------------------

    PS C:\>Example of how to use this cmdlet






    -------------------------- EXAMPLE 2 --------------------------

    PS C:\>Another example of how to use this cmdlet







RELATED LINKS
```

So, to add help to your own cmdlet, you simply need to stick that same comment block in your function.  You can place it in one of three spots:

- Before the function declaration
- After the function declaration(ewww)
- At the end of your function (not to be opininonated, but it is morally wrong to choose this option).

The docs give examples of each of [the approved locations here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-6#syntax-for-comment-based-help-in-functions) as well.